# Need some examples of self-similar algebraic objects with special properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

My knowledge in formal logic being too bad, let me define some concepts informally:

Let $A$ be some object of type $T$ (like, a set, a topological space, a group, a lie algebra, or everything you could think about). We say that $A$ is self-similar if there exists a strict subobject $B$ of $A$ of the same type $T$ (like, a subset, a subspace with subspace topology, a subgroup, a sub lie algebra, ...) that is $T$-isomorphic to $A$. That is, $A$ embeds into itself strictly.

Examples: any infinite set, $(\mathbb{Z},+,0)$ seen as a group, $]0,1[$ seen as a topological space, $\ldots$

Call ss-subobject of $A$ any strict subobject $B$ of $A$ isomorphic to $A$.

Now, we say that a self-similar object $A$ is maternal if there exists a maximal (for inclusion) ss-subobject $B$ (by this, I mean that $B$ is maximal in the poset of self-similar subobject of $A$, I don't care if $B$ isn't maximal in the lattice of non necessarily self-similar subobjects).

Examples: any infinite set, $(\mathbb{Z},+,0)$, $\mathbb{Q}$ seen as a topological space or a totally order set.

Non examples: $]0,1[$, the cantor set, $\ldots$

Finally, we say that a self-similar object $A$ is densely self-similar if for any ss-subobjects $B$ and $C$ of $A$ with $B < C$ (inclusion), there exists a ss-subobject $D$ with $B < D < C$.

Example: $]0,1[$ as a topological space.

It is clear that if $A$ is densely self-similar, then $A$ is not maternal (by contradiction).

Generally, does anyone have an example of non maternal $A$ that is non densely self-similar ?

More specifically, can we find an algebraic (i.e., non topological) example of non maternal structure $A$ ? Same for densely self-similar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any non-maternal self-similar object is densely self-similar.  Indeed, suppose $A$ is non-maternal and let $B<C$ be subobjects of $A$ which are isomorphic to $A$.  If there were no $D$ isomorphic to $A$ with $B<D<C$, then $B$ would be maximal among all proper subobjects of $C$ isomorphic to $C$, so $C$ would be maternal.  Since $A$ is isomorphic to $C$, $A$ would then also be maternal.

For an algebraic example of a densely self-similar object, let $R$ any integral domain which has no irreducible elements but is not a field (for instance, $R$ could be the ring of algebraic integers, which has no irreducible elements since every element has a square root).  Consider $R$ as a module over itself.  It is self-similar, since any nonzero non-unit $a\in R$ generates a proper submodule that is isomorphic to $R$.  But given any such proper submodule generated by $a$, the submodule generated by any nontrivial factor of $a$ is a strictly larger proper submodule which is isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: Oh indeed, sorry to have missed that, thanks for comment. I'm still very interested to find an example of non maternal algebraic object (of course, something relatively rigid like a group, a ring, a lattice, or things like that, not a semi-group or a monoid which are too "lax" imo)

Comment: I've added such an example.

Comment: Very nice example, thanks